# Help understanding proof regarding convergent sequence of measurable functions...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

*Note, measurable here means Lebesgue Measurable!*

I am currently reading through Real Analysis by Royden, and I have become stuck at the proof of Proposition 9 in Chapter 3. Below I will include the statement of Proposition 9 and the proof up to where I am getting stuck.

**Proposition 9:** Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $E$ that converges pointwise a.e. on $E$ to the function $f$. Then $f$ is measurable.

*Note, a.e. means almost everywhere.*

(Proof up to where I am getting stuck) **Proof:** Let $E_0$ be a subset of $E$ for which $m(E_0) = 0$ and $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ pointwise on $E \setminus E_0$. Since $m(E_0) = 0$, it follows from **Proposition 5** that $f$ is measurable if, and only if, its restriction to $E \setminus E_0$ is measurable. Therefore, by possibly replacing $E$ by $E \setminus E_0$, we may assume the sequence converges pointwise on all of $E$. Fix a number $c$. We must show that $\{x \in E:f(x) < c\}$ is measurable....

*Note, **Proposition 5** says, for a measurable subset $D$ of $E$, $f$ is measurable on $E$ if, and only if, the restrictions of $f$ to $D$ and $E \setminus D$ are measurable.*

I understand the proof up to that point and even the rest of the proof, however, I am not sure how you can replace $E$ by $E \setminus E_0$ in the proof... I am sure I am just missing some simple idea. Nevertheless, I am not understanding this.

Answer (score 1):

Note $\{x\in E: f(x)<c\}$ equals $$\tag 1  \{x\in E\setminus E_0: f(x)<c\}\cup \{x\in E_0: f(x)<c\}.$$ So if $f$ is measurable on $E\setminus E_0,$ the first set on the right of $(1)$ is measurable, while the second set is measurable by virtue of being a set of measure $0.$ So $\{x\in E: f(x)<c\}$ is the union of two measurable sets, hence is measurable.